# Balanced incomplete block design

Tags: anova, mathematical-statistics, experiment-design, combinatorics, blocking

In a BIBD, let

$a$ denote the number of treatments;

$b$ denote the number of blocks;

$k$ denote the number of treatments exactly in each block;

$\lambda$ is the number of times each pair of treatments appears in the same block.

Each treatment occurs $r$ times.

How are the relations 
$r=\binom{a-1}{k-1}$ and
$\lambda=\binom{a-2}{k-2}$ obtained?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give references for your claims? I don't think they are true, maybe they refer to some specific *subset* of BIBD's.

The number of experimental runs (total number of points) in A BIBD is $n$
which satisfies $n= ar = bk$ by simple combinatorics.  We have Fisher's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_inequality that $a \le b$, the number of treatments cannot exceed the number of blocks.

Less obvious is the relation $r (k-1) = \lambda (a-1)$, which can be proved by counting concentrating only on the blocks which contain one given treatment.

You give $r = \binom{a-1}{k-1}$ which I can prove **if** I assume the blocks consists of **all** $k$-subsets from the $a$ treatments, but many BIBD's are smaller than that.

One example which give counterexamples is 
$$
0000011122  \\
1123423433   \\
2345554545
$$
(each column is a block) which has
$$
a=6 \\
k=3 \\
b=10 \\
r=5 \\
\lambda=2
$$
and you can verify that
$$
\binom{a-1}{k-1}=\binom{5}{2}=10 \not = 5 = r \\
\binom{a-2}{k-2}=\binom{4}{1}=4 \not= 2 = \lambda
$$